# Binding 800000 records in Radgrid throwing timeout error

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am loading 800,000 records in the radgrid with custom paging, it's throwing timeout error. How can I get Radgrid to work with large a number (800,000) of records, this is my requirement. but I am able to bind 200,000 records in radgrid without any timeout or performance issue. So if anyone knows please suggest to me some options.

These are the following steps I have tried in my code: (**Kindly note: I am using the RadGrid within sharepoint 2007 as well as 2010**)

1. I am using custom paging and set the virtual item count is 800,000 and set the pagesize is 50
2. I am storing 800,000 records in viewstate, not binding all 800,000 records in radgrid, I am binding just 50 records at the time of loading the radgrid
3. If I change the paging in the radgrid, based on the page index I am getting 50 records from viewstate and bind it in the radgrid (for ex: current pageindex is 5 means I took 201 to 250)
4. Telerik support team says, don't use the viewstate, so I am storing all 800,000 records in property bag even though it's throwing time out error

please tell me what i need to do?

Comment: Can you post a stack trace? Where is the timeout occurring?

Comment: 800000 records in viewstate. If the grid doesn't timeout something else will!

Answer (score 2):

It's probably timing out because you are putting 800 thousand records in ViewState (They have to be serialized and sent over the wire to client. Insane!). I can imagine how "small" your page is.

I wouldn't put 800 thousand records in ViewState or even in Cache or Session. You could put a smaller amount if you want to avoid the round trip to the database and detect whether you have the records in memory or not. If not, you can get the next big chunk (say 500) and so on.

If you put smaller chunks, you are better off putting this in Cache (or Session) and getting them from there instead of the ViewState. In the case of Session in InProc mode, you won't have to worry about Serialization of the data; similarly for Cache.