# Best way to store 900000 records when binding the telerik radgrid with custom paging

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-2007

I am creating sample application in sharepoint 2010, i want to load 900000 records in telerik radgrid, so first i am storing all 900000 records in viewstate and get the 50 records from viewstate and bind it in radgrid due to the performance issue, but the page size goes to very huge, so it's throwing page timeout error, after that i store the 900000 records in SPWeb property bag instead of storing in viewstate eventhough it's throwing the same error, can anyone help me please.
 where i can able to store those (900000) values with out any timeout issue or performance issue, please help me

Comment: Why would anyone want to be presented with potentially 900000 records of data?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding 800000 records in Radgrid throwing timeout error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7714074/binding-800000-records-in-radgrid-throwing-timeout-error)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to store 900,000 records in viewstate. It is a horrible waste of resources, both client and server. And, if you are aiming for a custom paging solution, there is no reason to store all of the information on the client side. Yuck!

Consider reading an article like [Efficiently Paging Through Large Amounts of Data](http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-cs). A bit dated, but the basic concepts are sound. Looking at your query, getting the concepts down is important.

Comment: A waste of resources is a gentle way of saying it. Storing 900,000 records in ViewState will cripple the page completely.

Comment: @james Johnson: I am not sure "completely", as he may have the bandwidth to waste. ;-)

Comment: Others may not have the bandwidth to waste though. And even if he did have the bandwidth to waste, serving up a page of that size frequently will impact the performance of the server significantly.

Comment: LOL. I was being a bit sarcastic, actually. I would never have that much data (close to a million records) in viewstate. In some rare situations, maybe a server side cache, but it would depend on how many hits the data would receive. A few from a single user? Never

Answer (score 0):

ViewState is not a magical landfill for data. It is intended to hold state information for controls, and that's it. There are circumstances where people use it for other things, but it should never, ever be used to store large chunks of data.

As for your question, you need to implement some type of search or filtering system to reduce your results. There shouldn't be any scenario where you need to retrieve almost 1,000,000 results from the database.

If you can't implement searching, then use pagination and pass row boundaries to the stored procedure, so it only returns results for the current page.

Here's a quick example of how to use paging to limit results to one page:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetProductsPaged ( 
    @startRowIndex int, 
    @maximumRows int 
) AS

SELECT PriceRank, ProductName, UnitPrice 
FROM (SELECT ProductName, UnitPrice, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY UnitPrice DESC) AS PriceRank FROM Products ) AS ProductsWithRowNumber 
WHERE RowRank > @startRowIndex AND RowRank <= (@startRowIndex + @maximumRows)
```

And here's an article you can refer to for help with the above:
http://www.asp.net/data-access/tutorials/efficiently-paging-through-large-amounts-of-data-vb

**EDIT**

It doesn't sound like this information is user-specific in any way, so you could also look into caching the data, like this:

```
DataTable table = new DataTable("LotsOfData");

if (Cache.Get("MyData") == null) 
{ 
    //retrieve the data from the database
    table = GetLotsOfData();         

    //store the data in cache
    Cache.Insert("MyData", table); //store the data in cache
} 
else 
{ 
    //get the data from cache
    table = (DataTable)Cache.Get("MenuData"); 
}
```